# Sometimes restore, sometimes checkout

Tags: git, version-control

I've started to notice that sometimes when I type `git status` to check a branch I see the text:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   some_code_or_file.py
```

And sometimes I see:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   some_code_or_file.py
```

It's starting to freak me out. What's going on here?

Comment: Are you using different versions of git?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are almost certainly seeing these messages on two different computers or when running two different binaries at different versions. `git restore` [was introduced in 2.23](https://bluecast.tech/blog/git-switch-branch/), and the help message changed shortly after that (I can't remember exactly which version, and either it isn't mentioned in the [changelogs](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/Documentation/RelNotes) or I'm being dense and can't find it).

`git restore <file>` and `git checkout -- <file>` do the same thing, so there's no need to be worried about the difference beyond curiosity. `git checkout` is a mess of a command that does a ton of different things -- the introduction of `git switch` and `git restore` is an attempt to make it more intuitive for beginners, without changing functionality.

Comment: Thanks, yeah... I'm doing some stuff on a VM instance, and I didn't even make that distinction in my head.